Wpf datagrid leaves half a view empty on opening
I have a wpf application which uses MVVM. And a view which contains a datagrid in it. This datagrid contains near 30_000 rows. All columns are DataGridTextColumn and there is a OnSelectionChanged handler in code behind which just says dataGrid.ScrollIntoView so when I open this view I see last N rows and the last one is selected at the very bottom of view.
Now I added
<DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
    <Style>
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
    </Style>
</DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>

to the one of the columns, so height of some rows is changed and when I open the view the last row is placed near the center of view (it is still selected) and the bottom half of the datagrid area is empty.
Then after the first mouse click or scroll over the datagrid is redrawing it and last row takes its place at the very bottom of the view and all look and work fine.
I tried to change selected row in window_loaded handler but with no lack.
So the question is how to make wpf to evaluate datagrid correctly or just force it redraw datagrid after all evaluations made?

Have you tried to call ScrollIntoView from a DataGrid.Loaded event handler? You really provided absolutely no context for example how you initialize the control etc. A minimal reproducible example is always helpful for a code review. Right now we can only review 4 lines of boring XAML..

Well, now I tried to call ScrollIntoView from a DataGrid.Loaded event handler and it did not help.

As for context, it is quite complicated form, I think I should from creating a more simple one and check if text wrap will break it and if so I will be able to publish it here
